# MySQL Count cccurrence and join back same table

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I have the following table data:

```
ID DrawDate    DrawNumber
1  01/01/2014  1234
2  01/01/2014  1235
3  01/01/2014  1236
4  02/01/2014  1237
5  02/01/2014  1234
6  02/01/2014  1238
7  03/01/2014  1234
8  03/01/2014  1235
9  03/01/2014  1239
```

I would like to MySQL count the occurrence of DrawNumber, and populate back the result to be display as follows:

```
ID DrawDate    DrawNumber Occuurence
1  01/01/2014  1234       3
2  01/01/2014  1235       2
3  01/01/2014  1236       1
4  02/01/2014  1237       1
5  02/01/2014  1234       3
6  02/01/2014  1238       1
7  03/01/2014  1234       3
8  03/01/2014  1235       2
9  03/01/2014  1239       1
```

I managed to have the following MYSQL code, but it seems that it double up the total records of existing database.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT table.ID, table.DrawDATE,table.DrawNumber.
(SELECT
COUNT(table.ID)
FROM table
WHERE table1.DrawNumber = table.DrawNumber
) AS Occuurence

FROM table
INNER JOIN table AS table1 ON table.DrawNumber = table1.DrawNumber
ORDER BY table.DrawDATE DESC
```

Anyone can suggest better MySQL query?

Thanks in advance.

CK

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT a.ID, a.DrawDATE,a.DrawNumber,count(a.DrawNumber) as occurance
(select *  FROM table
ORDER BY table.DrawDATE DESC)a group by a.DrawNumber
```

If you don't want to use group by and if you want to keep same number of records in output same as in table then you can try below query:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT table.ID, table.DrawDATE,table.DrawNumber.
(SELECT
COUNT(table.ID)
FROM table
WHERE table1.DrawNumber = table.DrawNumber
) AS Occuurence

FROM table
ORDER BY table.DrawDATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Grateful to Ronak Shah for answering.

I use another method, in which I create a view to get the result of count and then join back the table.  It works fine.